# Current RecordSet Does not support updating

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm running into the following error, while trying to add data to the database (directly from Excel). I've noticed it's not working for users who have MS Office v1908 - but for example working for these who have v2002

> Error number: 3251. Current Recordset Does not support updating.

This may be a limitation of the provide or of the selected locktype. Any idea what might have been causing the issue?

```
Sub SendData()
  Dim dbpath        As String
  Dim dbtable       As String
  Dim result        As Long
  Dim iCNT          As Long
  Dim CNT           As ADODB.Connection
  Dim dbConnectStr  As String
  Dim rsCNT         As ADODB.Recordset
 
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ [DEFINE ERROR SITUATION]
Const sProcName As String = "[SendData]"
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ [GET ALL VARIABLES]
Call GetAllData
On Error Resume Next
Application.StatusBar = "Running... || " & sProcName
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.Cursor = xlWait

  dbpath = "'\\Database location.accdb'"
  dbtable = "[DailyReporting]"
  'AccPassWd = "test"
  dbConnectStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & dbpath '& ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & AccPassWd
  '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ CONNECTION ]
  Set CNT = New ADODB.Connection
  Set rsCNT = New ADODB.Recordset
  CNT.Open (dbConnectStr)
  rsCNT.Open dbtable, CNT, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
  '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ WRITE ]
  'rsCNT.MoveLast
  For iCNT = StartRangeRow To MaxLastRow
    rsCNT.AddNew
    rsCNT.Fields.Item(1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(iCNT, 3)                                      'Company / Location name - Location Code
    rsCNT.Fields.Item(2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(iCNT, 4)                                      'BANK - Currency - Bank account number
    rsCNT.Fields.Item(3).Value = Format(Sheet1.Cells(iCNT, 5), "yyyy-mm-dd;@")              'Statement Date
    rsCNT.Fields.Item(4).Value = Sheet1.Cells(iCNT, 6)                                      'Cash Application Status
    rsCNT.Fields.Item(5).Value = Sheet1.Cells(iCNT, 7)                                      'Bank Reconciliation Status
    rsCNT.Fields.Item(6).Value = Sheet1.Cells(iCNT, 8)                                      'Cash In Items (Total Deposit Items)
    rsCNT.Fields.Item(7).Value = Sheet1.Cells(iCNT, 9)                                      'Cash In Amount (Total Deposit Amount)
    rsCNT.Fields.Item(8).Value = Sheet1.Range("D5")                                         'Team
    rsCNT.Fields.Item(9).Value = Sheet1.Range("D3")                                         'User ID
    rsCNT.Fields.Item(10).Value = Sheet1.Range("D4")                                        'User Name
    rsCNT.Fields.Item(11).Value = Format(Sheet1.Range("D6"), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss;@")       'Reporting date (from Excel)
    rsCNT.Fields.Item(12).Value = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss;@")                    'Sending date & time
    'rsCNT.Fields.Item(13).Value = Format(Time, "hh:mm:ss;@")                                'Sending time
    rsCNT.Fields.Item(13).Value = UserNameStart                                             'Sending User ID
    rsCNT.Fields.Item(14).Value = UserFullNameStart                                         'Sending User Name
    rsCNT.Update
  Next iCNT
  rsCNT.Close
  CNT.Close
  '-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  [ MESSAGE BOX ]
  MsgBox "Data has been sent!", vbInformation
```

Comment: Seems like this should just work, barring the file actually being read-only. However, you can try swapping `adOpenKeyset` with `adOpenDynamic`, that's the one that's generally used for updating.

Comment: Hi, didn't help. I've noticed the error occurs on rsCNT.AddNew line. Any ideas why?